# Titanium Appcelerator **BUILD FAILED**

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Getting the following error when I try to run my program on an iOS device

[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild

[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **

There is no other information displayed in the console about why the build has failed. I don't think my code is the issue because

1. It runs fine on the simulator, and
2. I tried running an example "Hello World" app and the same error occurred

I have recently updated my certificates and provision profiles, which is when this error started occurring.

I am running:

- Node.js Version = 8.9.1
- npm Version = 5.5.1
- Appcelerator studio Version = 5.1.1.201809051655
- Titanium SDK Version = 7.5.0.GA
- Xcode Version = 10.1

Based on other forum posts that I have read, I have tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Using an older version of the Titanium SDK
- Deleting old provision profiles from Xcode
- Deleting old certificates from the keychain
- Assigning correct provision profile and certificate from Run > Run Configurations
- Removing modules used on the project
- Using devices with different versions of iOS

Really at a loss of what else to try. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can run `appc run -p ios --log-level trace` which will invoke the `xcodebuild` command with the highest possible log level. After that, the actual error will be shown. Most likely you are using a 3rd party module that is missing a framework link. If you got the log, you can paste it into a GitHub Gist and send it here, then we can find it for sure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Using the extra information from the trace log level I was able to figure out the problem. It was giving 

error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "<redacted>" with a private key was found.

So by fiddling around with the certificates I was able to get it up and running. (I think I was missing an Apple worldwide certificate).